# Why is Makecert.exe "for testing purposed only"?

Tags: .net, security

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx states that the makecert tool is for testing purposes only.

I realize you wouldn't want to distribute a self-signed certificate in a production scenario, but the tool also allows you to sign a certificate with an issuer's certificate.  So, would it make sense to purchase a certificate from a certificate authority, keep it as safe as possible, and only use it for the signing of other certificates (possibly generated by makecert)?  In that case, if one of those certificates where compromised, you could revoke it and issue a new one without purchasing another certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a purchased certificate to sign other certificates, those certificates will be rejected by the browsers, as the certificate you purchased does not have the CA bit set, and should not.

If you could issue certificates with a valid purchased certificate and have browsers accept those, what would stop you from issuing a certificate for say google.com and do man-in-the-middle attacks.

On a side note, there was recently a bug in iOS that allowed you to use certificates issued by a non CA without warning.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are a Certificate Authority (CA), how do you expect to reliably revoke those certificates?

I will quote from a [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-self-signed-ssl-certificates) answer on self-signed certificates:

> In general it is bad to use a self signed cert. If you do that then
>   you are running the risk people will leave your site when they get a
>   warning about your cert being bad. More important, you are running a
>   larger risk of having someone do an injection attack where they use
>   their own self-signed cert in the place of yours and the visitor will
>   not know any better.
>
> Check out the article here,
>   http://www.sslshopper.com/article-when-are-self-signed-certificates-acceptable.html
>   for a little more info on it.
>
> As Adam suggested in the comments, I would try
>   http://www.startssl.com/?app=1. If that doesn't suit your needs I know
>   GoDaddy sells certs for as low as $24.99/yr here,
>   http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx?ci=9039.